What is the meaning of a sentence from Agatha Christie (*Murder of Roger Ackroyd*)?
The sentence is from a paragraph (Murder of Roger Ackroyd) as below;

“Did Poirot ask you any more questions?” I inquired.
“Only about the patients you had that morning.”
“The patients?” I demanded, unbelievingly.
“Yes, your surgery patients. How many and who they were?”
“Do you mean to say you were able to tell him that?” I demanded. Caroline is really amazing.
“Why not?” asked my sister triumphantly. “I can see the path up to the surgery door perfectly from this window. And I’ve got an excellent memory, James. Much better than yours, let me tell you.”
“I’m sure you have,” I murmured mechanically.
My sister went on, checking the names on her fingers.
“There was old Mrs. Bennett, and that boy from the farm with the bad finger, Dolly Grice to have a needle out of her finger; that American steward off the liner. Let me see—that’s four. Yes, and old George Evans with his ulcer. And lastly——”
She paused significantly.
“Well?”
Caroline brought out her climax triumphantly. She hissed in the most approved style—aided by the fortunate number of s’s at her disposal.
“Miss Russell!”


The Story you are reading "Murder of Roger Ackroyd" was written around 1926 , when there were various idioms / slang terms / contemporary phrases / other variations which might not sound natural now.
The phrase / idiom / term "most approved style" meant that some thing was just perfect , according to almost everybody.
It was also used sarcastically to indicate the exact opposite , that something was absolutely not right , at least to the recipient.
Those days "hissing" was frowned upon , maybe due to connections with snakes or dental issues , which sounds jarring to our ears. That continues to current times : School teachers do not want students to hiss unnecessarily : Students should not speak like "Thissss isssss the bessssst classsssssss"
Here Caroline was saying "Miss Russell!" like "Misssssss Russsssssell!" , dragging it out , which is jarring to the narrator , who claims that Caroline has too many "s" sounds / letters available.
Since it is jarring , the narrator sarcastically says it is the "most approved style" , to let us know the displeasure.
Later , we find out that the hissing was not the only thing jarring. The information which Caroline shared is itself jarring to the narrator.
Caroline spoke with the pause and the climax , which adds to the displeasure.
Putting all together , the narrator is thoroughly displeased to sarcastically say that things are perfect.
ADDENDUM :
Phrase "most approved style" was common around 1840 to 1940 , according to google ngrams viewer :

Here are a few articles where that is used :
"A Debate between Two Southern Orators of the Old School" 1923 : available here
"The New School of American Humor" : 1877 : available here
Greens Dictionary of Slang gives this Example : 1885 : available here :
"One of the larrikins present made use of some abominable language to her. Upon this she ‘went for him’ in most approved style, and landed him one in the eye."
We can make out that the usage was generally sarcastic , though not always.
Currently , it has fallen into dis-use , though other variations have taken over.

ooh and the extra diagram is very nice as well!

"who claims that Caroline has too many "s" sounds / letters available" - specifically, because "Miss Russell" has a whopping four of them. It would be comparatively harder to hiss out "Lady Brown", for example...

Nicely put , @MaciejStachowski , Caroline could easily take it beyond eight to twelve !

Literally it means that she hissed

to make a noise like a long s sound

where the Ss would indeed help.  But it also implies another meaning

to say something in a quiet angry way:

That is, she is pointing out that she knew of all his patients, and that most meant nothing important, and that Miss Russell was significant -- despite his belief she did not know
Exactly why she is underscoring this would need more context.
